# What is the best method for Backend and Frontend communication (incl. SessionID)?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, frontend, backend

I have a small project running and I question myself, how to do it. I host on two server. One is for Backend and one for Frontend. The Backend-Server is running on NodeJS and as DB MongoDB and I already have my own small API to communicate with it. On the Frontend-Server I am using React. My Question now: What is the best way to make a SessionID on the Frontend and Send it to the Backend-Server over the Frontend-Server? [image]

For example SessionID3 should get displayed a bike on his site and SessionID2 a car (both informations are stored on the Backend-Server on the DB).

I look forward to any replies, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Most Jamstack setups have an API server that serves content in the form of `json/raw` (like [Github's developer API](https://api.github.com/))in which Nodejs and JavaScript has a built in feature which allows the quick conversion to a JSON object with references in which you can read about that on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON).

[Diagram of Jamstacking with React & Vue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2zEy.png)

^ since it is actually the client sending the request and doing most of the work and not the front-end server, you can use [`universal-cookie`](https://github.com/reactivestack/cookies/tree/master/packages/universal-cookie) to set or get a session ID **permanently**, parse it into JSON and send with the POST request to the Back-end API. You could also do this with `Math.random(min, max)` as well of you just want a random string of numbers to be sent.

Axios is asynchronous so you want to use `async/await` or `.then()` with it so that it works correctly. You can view the official docs at https://axios-http.com/docs/intro. The value returned by Axios is the response in which you will want to parse the "body" the header returned so it can be used.

Another alternative to get the **browser session id** (which is erased after the browser is closed) is a module called [react-session-hook](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-session-hook)

In my opinion, for what you are trying to do, adding another server that relays the message is not optimal as that adds another sequential connection that makes things take twice as long as it would otherwise. In other-words, this is not necessary. The only time you do this is if the keys to access the API are **sensitive** meaning they contain important information and musts be hidden.

Comment: Thank you very much. I dont really want the client to communicate directly with the Backend since the Backend Server handles Payments and for safety reasons I want to hide the Backend Server as good as possible. Any other ways/ideas?

Comment: @YourLocalCoder I'll update it for that but it is more complex since react can't do that (you have to create another server).

Comment: @YourLocalCoder It is a bit unnecessary for what you are trying to do